# How do I use macros created with CMake add_compile_definitions and list argument?

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-language

A relevant fragment of my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
add_executable(hello main.cpp)
set(helloCompileOptions -Wall -Wextra -O3 -Wno-narrowing -ffast-math -march=native)
target_compile_options(hello PRIVATE ${helloCompileOptions})
target_compile_features(hello PUBLIC cxx_std_23)
add_compile_definitions(COMPILE_OPTIONS="${helloCompileOptions}")
```

produces these compilation errors:

```
[build] <command line>:1:9: error: macro name must be an identifier
[build]     1 | #define -O3 1
[build]       |         ^
[build] <command line>:2:9: error: macro name must be an identifier
[build]     2 | #define -Wextra 1
[build]       |         ^
...
```

How should I handle the `helloCompileOptions` list, so it compiles and is avalable as a string to my C++ code?

Comment: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WfhxYzev8), AI coding assistance are pretty good at fixing funky CMake syntax errors.

Comment: @haleyk I didn't know CMake can do string processing. I will post a simpler solution in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Using CMake string processing:

```
add_executable(hello main.cpp)
set(compileOptions -Wall -Wextra -O3 -Wno-narrowing -ffast-math -march=native)
target_compile_options(hello PRIVATE ${compileOptions})
target_compile_features(hello PUBLIC cxx_std_23)
string(JOIN " " compileOptionsStr ${compileOptions})
target_compile_definitions(hello PUBLIC COMPILE_OPTIONS="${compileOptionsStr}")
```

makes this line:

```
  cout << COMPILE_OPTIONS << "\n";
```

produce:

```
-Wall -Wextra -O3 -Wno-narrowing -ffast-math -march=native
```