# Can C++ compile-time constants have a different value for each compiled binary?

Tags: c++, constants

Say my entire repo relies on a compile-time constant:

```
// consts.h
constexpr int MAGIC_CONST = 10;
```

Then I can use it in my main function:

```
// main.cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // use MAGIC_CONST to do something:
  double data[MAGIC_CONST];
}
```

Now, say I want to compile several "instances" of this main: `main_1.cpp`, `main_2.cpp`, ..., each with a different `MAGIC_CONST`. How do I do this? Because `MAGIC_CONST` is defined in the header and is unique for the entire codebase and not per-binary.

I've also (clumsily) tried using extern const like this:

```
// consts.h
extern const int MAGIC_CONST; // declaration only
```

Then define its actual value in each main:

```
// main_0.cpp
extern const int MAGIC_CONST = 10;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  double data[MAGIC_CONST];
}
```

This won't work either since `extern const` is not a compile-time constant.

I've also thought about old-style `#define`s but I actually need to use my `MAGIC_CONST` elsewhere in the codebase too and not just in `main_0.cpp`.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: kind of sounds like you should just compile, edit the variable, and compile again - no?

Comment: You can use [variable template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) to achieve the same effect as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78045202/12002570).

Comment: Usually you can pass in "#defines" at compile time via command line arguments, which you can then assign to constexpr values. This s the documentation for msvc compiler [/D (Preprocessor Definitions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/d-preprocessor-definitions?view=msvc-170). Or you can let your build system generate a header file for you (e.g. with build version info) and include that.

Comment: Adding this kind of constants at compile time might make your code harder to test. So if a bit too much memory, why not make data a std::vector<double>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [variable template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) as shown below:

**header.h**

```
#pragma once
template<int i> constexpr int variable = i;
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
  constexpr int j = variable<10> ;//works   
}
```

**source.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"

constexpr int k = variable<11>;
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/jC_i10kJE9)

Comment: As much for the questioner as for the answerer, how is this meaningfully different from just having several variables with different names and values?

Comment: Thanks very much I think I'll go with this. On the back of my mind I was thinking, the main issue is I can't have a single source.cpp compile into multiple .o's based on the constant. And template makes the perfect sense.

Comment: @DavisHerring It saves some keystrokes like instead of writing `constexpr int i = 10` we can just write `variable<10>`

Comment: @DavisHerring Fair point. In the example given above there is no meaningful difference. However in my actual code I have a fairly chunky utility class dependent on that constant. So in fact it makes sense to just templatize my chunky utility class on that int value.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `-D` while compiling?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", MAGIC_CONST);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
PS F:\OtherApps\Program\VsCode\Code> g++ main.cpp -D MAGIC_CONST=1 -o main_1.exe
PS F:\OtherApps\Program\VsCode\Code> ./main_1.exe
1
PS F:\OtherApps\Program\VsCode\Code> g++ main.cpp -D MAGIC_CONST=2 -o main_2.exe
PS F:\OtherApps\Program\VsCode\Code> ./main_2.exe
2
PS F:\OtherApps\Program\VsCode\Code>
```

You can also write a script or `.bat` to compile different executable binarys

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I knew the `-D` with a loop solution is always possible however I'm pretty bad at writing build scripts so was hesitant on making that more complex.

Comment: @user961665 You can easily manage them with [CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77755317/how-do-i-use-macros-created-with-cmake-add-compile-definitions-and-list-argument)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by compile-time constant: at headers’ library target compile time, or at each of the sources’ executable target compile time.

If your intent is to have an ‘extern’ compile-time constant, consider writing [consteval](https://godbolt.org/z/r4YhKT6Kn).

Answer (score 0):

`const` non-`inline` non-template non-`extern` variables in C++ actually have internal linkage, meaning that they are different in each translation unit.

Therefore it is perfectly fine to not include the general header in one translation unit and define the constant differently in such a unit instead or to have two headers with different definitions.

However, you must be careful to not cause ODR violations e.g. because an `inline` function or a class uses the constant and it has a different value in two translation units which both define the entity. (You have this problem with any other solution as well. With a `-D` compiler option especially the risk is much higher, because the header separation of definitions doesn't guarantee anymore that there isn't a mismatch.)